# Rfid reading using java getting error in output

Tags: java, sockets, networking, server

I am using RFID technology.Here client is my RFID machine and i am writing server code.but my problem is that I am getting same answer on console while showing different RFID tags.I am totally confused at this point because I'am new to rfid.

Advance thanks

Here is my code.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Serverc {
    final protected static char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
    public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
        for ( int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++ ) {
            int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
            hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
            hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
        }
        return new String(hexChars);
    }
    public static void connection() throws IOException
    {
      ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(9888);
      ss.setSoTimeout(30000000);
      System.out.println("Waiting for client on port " +
                ss.getLocalPort() + "...");
      while(true)
      {
          try{
              Socket server = ss.accept();
          System.out.println("Just connected to "
                + server.getRemoteSocketAddress());
          DataInputStream in =
                  new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());
          int input = 0;
          //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);

          byte byteArr[] = new byte[32];
//        example.getBytes();
          while((input = in.read(byteArr)) != -1)
          {
              System.out.println("Size read is " + input);
              System.out.println("Data is " + bytesToHex(byteArr));
          }
          server.close();
          }
          catch(SocketTimeoutException ex){
              System.out.println("Socket timed out!");
          }
          try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
      //server.close();

    }
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        Serverc obj=new Serverc();
        obj.connection();


    }
}
```

here is my console(PLEASE NOTE:I showed different RFID card but getting same data)

```
Waiting for client on port 9888...
Just connected to /106.208.71.50:61532
Size read is 28
Data is 55000016910001DB00FB63ABEEAFC1EC888F10263410050711148F3500000000
Size read is 28
Data is 55000016910001DB00FB63ABEEAFC1EC888F10263410050711148F3500000000
Size read is 28
Data is 55000016910001DB00FB63ABEEAFC1EC888F10263410050711148F3500000000
Size read is 28
Data is 55000016910001DB00FB63ABEEAFC1EC888F10263410050711148F3500000000
Size read is 28
Data is 55000016910001DB00FB63ABEEAFC1EC888F10263410050711148F3500000000
```

Comment: maybe your server is sending the same data.  without seeing the code I can not tell.

Comment: @Scary Wombat: the above class is my server class.my client is my rfid machine

Comment: Sorry, I was meaning the application(s) that is sending the data.

Comment: is there any fault in this portion

while((input = in.read(byteArr)) != -1)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the output, only one client connects during the lifetime of your server (the "Just connected to" line is only printed once)... The only way I can see this output produced is if the first RFID card sends its data 5 times.

Since you are never disconnecting the client (the RFID card), you are relying on it to disconnect and it seems like it does not :).

You can either disconnect it yourself after reading a number of bytes you need, or you could spawn a new thread for each Socket you get from `Socket server = ss.accept()`. In your current code, you will not let a second RFID connect unless the first one is disconnected.

Comment: In my code i closed my (Socket server = ss.accept()) as (server.close()).but it does not close the Socket object.Any other methods can we used to do the same?

Comment: The line server.close() is never reached, because in.read() would only return -1 if end of stream is detected, but the RFID client probably never closes the socket.

Comment: okay but how to close the socket by client(here client is my RFIDmachine) after reading the entire stream.?

Comment: My understanding is that you have no control over the RFID machine itself (the client). If it does not close the connection itself, then you need to figure out what "entire stream" means to you. If you know that each RFID card will have a 28-byte id, then you just read 28 bytes and disconnect, otherwise as long as the card is within its range, it will keep your socket busy and no other card will be able to connect.